# What does the word 「よっとな！」　mean?

Tags: words, manga

It is said by a guy who is bullying another one by twisting his hand. Is it related to Kansai dialect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with a dialect.

「よっとな」 is just one of the many versions of the shouts (chants?) people use as they make a ***physical movement*** of some sort such as lifting up an object, pushing or pulling an object, handing or tossing an object to another person, etc.

Similar versions include:

あらよっと、そらよっと、こらよっと、はいよっと、よっこらせ, etc.

All of these mean "Here we go!", "Like this!", "One, two, go!", etc.

Answer (score 0):

よっと is a grunt or shout of effort.  The addition of な is a variant of the same line.  I would translate it as "Huh!" "Like this!" depending on the situation.
As far as whether or not it's a Kansai dialect thing, I don't believe so, but I'm no expert in that area so don't quote me there.